# How to resolve/debug oAuth authentication errors in dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am working on a dataflow pipeline and I am running into oAuth authentication errors all the time and I am using a service account to run the jobs

I am using the apache beam io to connect to the source and sink

1. GCS: apache_beam.io.gcsio.GcsIO
2. Pub-Sub:  apache_beam.io.ReadFromPubSub
3. BQ: apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery_tools.BigQueryWrapper

**Permission for service account:** Dataflow Admin, Pub-Sub Admin, GCS Admin, BQ Admin

The command I run:

`python3.8 test1.py     --project=******    --region=us-central1     --input_topic=projects/******/topics/******     --output_path=gs://******/samples/output     --runner=DataflowRunner     --window_size=1     --num_shards=1     --temp_location=gs://******/temp     --subnetwork=https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/******/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/subnet01     --service_account_email=dataflow@******.iam.gserviceaccount.com     --disable_public_ips --enable_streaming_engine --max_workers=3 --no_use_public_ips`

Errors in Logs explorer:

`"2022-01-24T17:04:13.4377Z OSConfigAgent Error policies.go:49: Error running LookupEffectiveGuestPolicies: error calling LookupEffectiveGuestPolicies: code: "Unauthenticated", message: "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.", details: []"`

Comment: Does the service account have the required access?

Comment: yes service account has below roles
network user, dataflow worker, dataflow admin, storage admin, pub sub admin, bq admin

Comment: Can you provide some more details about the operation that is being performed when the OAuth error occurs?

Comment: I did reach out to the GCP customer support team, looks like there is a defect tracked on the same. Thanks @KennKnowles
[link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198426271)
In general, I am trying to read from pub-sub and write to BQ and failure records to GCS